# Vue 3 Render Function: App Mounts Inside Root Element via innerHTML Instead of Replacing It

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, migration

How do I do it on Vue 3 so that the root element is replaced by the rendered app instead of appending it inside the root element?

I am currently migrating our vue 2 to vue 3. I know that I can just deal with the root element being rendered but the app is a bit large and a lot are dependent on the App being rendered without the root element. So maybe there is a workaround to keep the expected behaviour or simulate the vue 2.x behavior?

## How I render

```js
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import ContentApp from '@js/ContentApp';

const app = createApp({
  render: () => h(ContentApp, { ... }),
});
app.use(store);
app.mount('#vueContent');
```

```html
<!-- In DOM, the App renders on innerHtml of the root element (#vueContent) -->
<body>
    <div class="layout-base">
        <div id="vueContent">
            <!-- APP -->
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <!-- content -->
            </div>
            <!-- APP -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

## What I expect

```html
<!-- In DOM, I expect that the App will replace the root element ('#vueContent')-->
<body>
    <div class="layout-base">
        <!-- APP -->
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
        <!-- APP -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way as a workaround to mimic the behaviour of vue 2.x app mounting by using fragments.

```js
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import ContentApp from '@js/ContentApp';

const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
const targetEl = document.getElementById('vueContent');

const app = createApp({
  render: () => h(ContentApp, { ... }),
});
app.use(store);
// Temporarily mount the vue app on the fragment
app.mount(fragment);

// Now replace the target element with the fragment that has the app
targetEl.parentNode.replaceChild(fragment, targetEl);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Vue 3 Migration Guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/mount-changes.html#mounted-application-does-not-replace-the-element): **Mounted application does not replace the element**

While in Vue 2 the HTML element selector is replaced, on Vue 3 the mount function will create content inside the selector.

Comment: That is right. But is there a workaround? Or should I just deal with it?